# Filter for Autoreplies in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to filter my incoming Gmail messages and exclude messages that are auto-replies.  I was hoping to search against for "does not have the words" `X-Autoreply: yes`, referencing the email header, but it seems like Gmail doesn't compare against that header.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there isn't any way to filter message headers using normal Gmail headers.  However, since I'm using a Google Apps account, I was able to implement the filter through the Google Apps Control Panel using the [Content Compliance](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1346934) feature:

1. I created a new sub-organization
2. I added the email account I want this filter to apply to into that organization
3. I created a Content Compliance setting that checked for the header `X-Autoresponse: yes` and changed the routing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to identify some of the automated emails is to search for `From:noreply@` or `subject:(Out of Office AutoReply)` as part of your filter system.

You should be able to identify other portions of subjects or email addresses as you start to filter though your emails. Remember, more than one filter can use the same label.

Other possibilities include:

- confirmation@
- unattended mail box or unattended mailbox as part of the message.

Comment: These are great ideas, although (somewhat complicated) by the fact that I'm actually trying to *exclude* auto-replies from my filter, not include them, which can lead to some funky logic with a lot of ORs and NOTs.